# Can school-laptop be monitored on Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04

I am using my school-laptop because I don’t have one. It have two OS( Ubuntu and windows). Windows shows “Your PC is monitored and protected “ and I want to know if my school can monitor the laptop if I use Ubuntu.

Comment: I've been thinking about this question and it isn't clear. Did the school install Ubuntu, or is that something you personally did? If the school installed the OS, there's some potential that they're logging your activity in part or in whole.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the relevant information mentioned in the last comment.

Comment: @KGIII There are certain parental control software, e.g. [GNOME Nanny](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Nanny/)   ;-) but they do not seem to be a surveillance software. I don't know if any remotely accessible surveillance software exists in Ubuntu, but what you guessed may be true. We should wait for OP to respond.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I was thinking **also** along the lines of things like [this](https://ostechnix.com/monitor-user-activity-linux/). I haven't ever spent any time searching for tools to monitor user activity, though I suppose there are likely other choices for monitoring Linux desktops in an enterprise. If installed by a school, they could easily automate logging in and retrieving that sort of data.

Answer (score 1):

"*Your PC is monitored and protected*" -- Is that the antivirus (Windows Defender) ? It may mean that the antivirus is "monitoring" your PC to protect against malware, and may have nothing to do with your school's surveillance.

In Ubuntu there is no need to use an antivirus for malware protection. Of course, if you use the school's network, they may monitor how you use their network, but they certainly cannot see which programs you run in Ubuntu, or which files you access.

If you format the Ubuntu partition as `ext4` (which is the default option), Windows cannot even access the partition where Ubuntu is installed.

Comment: I've been thinking about this and the original question isn't clear. If it's a *school installed* Ubuntu, it's quite possible that they've installed some sort of monitoring software. If they themselves installed Ubuntu, there's absolutely no monitoring at the OS level unless they themselves set it up. But... If the school did it, there's no telling what they've installed without digging into it. Please do correct me if I'm mistaken.